# Amount of light blocked by a body at the Earth-Sun L1 point

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, geometric-optics

I came across [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102489/how-big-would-a-satellite-need-to-be-to-block-out-the-sun) on the World Building SE. It has an accepted answer but it seems to be under some debate (see comments). So I thought I'd put it to some physicists:

What formula would describe the amount of light blocked by a body of a given radius placed at the L1 Lagrangian point?

Comment: Do you want to know how much light it blocks, or the size of its shadow?  The first is easy: it blocks al the light that falls on it, and that's easy to compute.  Size of the shadow is harder.

Comment: I just want the amount of light blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The L1 Lagrange point is at a distance of [approximately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#L1):

$$D_{\oplus\text{-}\rm L1}=D_{\odot\text{-}\oplus}\left(\frac{{\rm M}_\oplus}{3{\rm M}_\odot}\right)^{1/3}$$

from Earth. An object of linear size $L$ subtends an angular size, in radians, of $\Theta=L/D$ (assuming that the size is much smaller than the distance, which in this case it is). The [angular size of the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter) is about $\Theta_\odot = 0.5^\circ=0.01\,{\rm rad}$. The fraction of light blocked $f_L$ is proportional to the square of the ratio of the angular sizes (assuming here a round object):

$$f_{L} = \left(\frac{L}{\Theta_\odot D_{\rm \oplus\text{-}L1}}\right)^2$$

This is valid if $\Theta < \Theta_\odot$; if you make the object any bigger than the light is completely blocked and $f_L=1$, obviously. I've neglected some geometric details here, most importantly that the light source has finite size/is not distant enough for the wavefront to be completely flat. A more realistic treatment would involve thinking along [these](https://www.imgtec.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/PowerVR-Ray-Tracing-soft-shadows.gif) lines.

Comment: This seems to agree with the answer to the question on world building. Does it mean the problems brought up in the comments aren't valid?

Comment: @FreeElk The problems in the comments have to do with whether the satellite casts an umbral or penumbral shadow. This matters (a lot) if you want to know the brightness at a given location, but this answer should be accurate as long as you just want total light blocked averaged across the entire surface. It's still not exact because you have to worry about some details of the geometry, but it'll be close (not off by a factor of 10).

Comment: @KyleOman, precise calculations show, that at Θ=Θ⊙, the actual amount of blocked light is 60%, and penumbral shadow is twice the size of Earth. To block it off completely you'll need at least Θ=2Θ⊙. Your formula is valid for fL < 40%, which covers the region that the author of the original question on worldbuilding addresses.

Comment: @ZuOverture I know comments are pretty limiting so you couldn't fit it here but as it is stating "precise calculations show" with no other explanation isn't convincing me. Would you mind writing an answer spelling it out a little more?

Comment: @FreeElk, I've calculated the penumbral shadow radius at Earth position. Then I've created a blocking function, which is basically a relative area of the intersection of Sun circle and shadowing satellite circle. It was somewhat 40% at the edge of the Earth, if the umbral shadow (which is a single point under these conditions) is positioned precisely on the Sun-Earth line. Then I've integrated the blocking function across the Earth area, assuming it's flat, and got 60% average shadow density. Formula validity area starts where penumbral shadow lies within the Earth surface completely.